# Calculating hours logged into system when able to login to multiple queues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Our agents can log in to the phone system throughout the day they can log into and out of multiple queues assigned to them.

This creates an issue for me trying to calculate the total time they are logged into the system for the day.

Here is a single day pulled for an agent.

```
ID      USERID              GROUPID             STARTTIME                   ENDTIME ts
53265   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 15:01:30.0000000 2015-11-23 16:31:07.0000000 2015-11-23 16:31:08.0000000
53264   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 15:01:30.0000000 2015-11-23 16:31:07.0000000 2015-11-23 16:31:08.0000000
53263   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 15:01:30.0000000 2015-11-23 16:31:07.0000000 2015-11-23 16:31:08.0000000
53262   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 15:01:30.0000000 2015-11-23 16:31:07.0000000 2015-11-23 16:31:08.0000000
53293   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 16:38:27.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000
53292   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 16:38:27.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000
53291   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 16:38:27.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000
53296   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 16:40:24.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000
53303   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 17:46:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:20:25.0000000 2015-11-23 18:20:26.0000000
53302   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 17:46:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:20:25.0000000 2015-11-23 18:20:25.0000000
53301   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 17:46:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:20:25.0000000 2015-11-23 18:20:25.0000000
53300   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 17:46:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:20:25.0000000 2015-11-23 18:20:25.0000000
53312   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 18:21:11.0000000 2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000 2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000
53311   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 18:21:11.0000000 2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000 2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000
53310   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 18:21:11.0000000 2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000 2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000
53309   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 18:21:11.0000000 2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000 2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000
53319   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 18:46:29.0000000 2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000
53318   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 18:46:29.0000000 2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000
53317   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 18:46:29.0000000 2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000
53316   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 18:46:29.0000000 2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000
53321   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 18:54:23.0000000 2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000 2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000
53324   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 18:54:23.0000000 2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000 2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000
53323   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 18:54:23.0000000 2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000 2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000
53322   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 18:54:23.0000000 2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000 2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000
53338   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 20:34:04.0000000 2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000 2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000
53337   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 20:34:04.0000000 2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000 2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000
53336   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 20:34:04.0000000 2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000 2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000
53335   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 20:34:04.0000000 2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000 2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000
53343   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 20:42:56.0000000 2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000 2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000
53342   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 20:42:56.0000000 2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000 2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000
53341   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 20:42:56.0000000 2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000 2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000
53340   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 20:42:56.0000000 2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000 2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000
53364   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 21:55:55.0000000 2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000 2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000
53363   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 21:55:55.0000000 2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000 2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000
53362   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 21:55:55.0000000 2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000 2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000
53361   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 21:55:55.0000000 2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000 2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000
53371   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 22:07:21.0000000 2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000 2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000
53370   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 22:07:21.0000000 2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000 2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000
53369   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 22:07:21.0000000 2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000 2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000
53368   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 22:07:21.0000000 2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000 2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000
53381   7469291810335714    3466233807211157283 2015-11-23 22:46:58.0000000 2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000 2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000
53380   7469291810335714    3466233806423685334 2015-11-23 22:46:58.0000000 2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000 2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000
53379   7469291810335714    3466233806542064445 2015-11-23 22:46:58.0000000 2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000 2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000
53378   7469291810335714    3466233807109235583 2015-11-23 22:46:58.0000000 2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000 2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000
```

As we can see with the first four lines it is pretty straight forward.  They logged into four different queues at the exact same time and logged out at the exact same time.

But the next time the logged in (next set of 4 lines) they logged into three seperate queues and then a couple minutes later logged into the fourth queue.

This makes it difficult for me to correctly calculate the time since every query I have tried has incorrectly added this time to their total.

My main query to grab all of the data:

```
select *
from ##agentlogin
where userid = '7469291810335714'
and starttime between @monday_start_datetime and @monday_end_datetime
```

This query is as close to perfect as I can get it, but it incorrectly adds that time for the fourth queue.

```
select userid, endtime, min(starttime), max(endtime), datediff(ss, starttime, endtime)
    from ##agentlogin
    where userid = '7469291810335714'
    and starttime between @monday_start_datetime and @monday_end_datetime
    group by userid, endtime, starttime



userid              endtime                     (No column name)           (No column name) (No column name)
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 16:31:07.0000000 2015-11-23 15:01:30.0000000 2015-11-23 16:31:07.0000000 5377
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000 2015-11-23 16:38:27.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000 3032
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000 2015-11-23 16:40:24.0000000 2015-11-23 17:28:59.0000000 2915
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 18:20:25.0000000 2015-11-23 17:46:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:20:25.0000000 2043
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000 2015-11-23 18:21:11.0000000 2015-11-23 18:42:57.0000000 1306
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:46:29.0000000 2015-11-23 18:53:22.0000000 413
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000 2015-11-23 18:54:23.0000000 2015-11-23 20:00:22.0000000 3959
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000 2015-11-23 20:34:04.0000000 2015-11-23 20:40:49.0000000 405
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000 2015-11-23 20:42:56.0000000 2015-11-23 21:52:17.0000000 4161
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000 2015-11-23 21:55:55.0000000 2015-11-23 21:58:31.0000000 156
7469291810335714    2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000 2015-11-23 22:07:21.0000000 2015-11-23 22:31:18.0000000 1437
7469291810335714    2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000 2015-11-23 22:46:58.0000000 2015-11-24 00:01:13.0000000 4455
```

As you can see in the above in the second line it correctly adds time for the first 3 queues, but then re-adds a portion of that time for when they logged into the fourth queue.

The first table at top is all of the information I have in this table.  The third line isn't even needed since line 2 cover all of that time already.

Comment: Are you looking for a single value sum of time logged in for the day?

Comment: I've prepared my answer. It's ready for your review. Let me know if that helped or not.

Comment: @gmiley yes that is the eventual goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James,

What you have is an example of poor design, since your data is missing an information about a session identifier which could make a potential column for a `GROUP BY` statement.

Your solution depends on all those queues being started and finished at the same time. If you'd like it to still be grouped together you'd have to allow small differences in minutes (truncation) to make a clear group, but that would be erroneous. **I wouldn't recommend that, though.**

> This creates an issue for me trying to calculate the total time they are logged into the system for the day.

I've quoted your need above, which I assume is your question.

Assumption from your data:

- When an agent loggs out he is logging out from every queue he's currently logged into

That would mean that you can take your current statement and extend it to get what you need. You only need to group your data again by `endtime` so that in your current output row 2 and row 3 would merge into 1 row preserving accurate start (minimum - log in action) and end (maximum - log out action) times. As for `timecalculated` you are only interested in the higher value, since it contains the lesser one, thus `max(timecalculated)` in the select.

```
select
    foo.userid, min(startmin) startmin, max(endmax) endmax, max(timecalculated) timecalculated
from (
    select      userid, endtime, min(starttime) startmin, max(endtime) endmax, datediff(ss, starttime, endtime) timecalculated
    from        ##agentlogin
    where       userid = '7469291810335714' and starttime between @monday_start_datetime and @monday_end_datetime
    group by    userid, endtime, starttime
    ) foo
group by foo.userid, foo.endtime
```

`sum()` would almost double the time in your case which isn't what you need, since you need to only count the time once.

Comment: I copied this over for a test and it gives me an error The column 'endtime' was specified multiple time for 'foo'.  Have not yet been able to work around it my self.

Comment: I agree on the bad design as well, this is third party software unfortunately and out of my control.

Comment: @JamesWilson `starttime` and `endtime` are directly accessed and aliased in the subquery. You can re-alias the max start and end time as `startmax` and `endmax`, just ensure any other places you are intending to use the max ones, fix those references as well.

Comment: Alright I was able to pass this through and it seems to be working just fine now, thank you.

Comment: I haven't tested it. Good point, I'm going to fix my answer to resolve ambiguities. Thanks @gmiley